# can I download wordpress theme and change it as I wish?

Tags: wordpress

I just saw a nice theme on WordPress, but I want to download it and change the code, and add PHP in my LAMP environment. Is it ok? Or it's copyrighted and I must use it only with WordPress?

Comment: Ask the theme author

Comment: Read the licence in the folder.